# SQL Server couldn't convert varchar value to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Using SSMS I discovered that a stored procedure I'm modifying has a return type of `integer` even though nowhere in the SQL code does it specify that an int will be returned (see screenshot). Why is this return type there and how can I change it?

Longer story - I have a stored procedure which at some point declares an `INT` variable and then returns that variable. I've modified the stored procedure so that this variable is a string. It all seems to work - the stored procedure does exactly what it is supposed to do.

However, after execution, I get an error message that it couldn't convert varchar value 'x' to data type int. Nowhere in the stored procedure code does it say it will return an `int`.

[image: Stored procedure parameters]

Comment: The return type of a stored procedure is always `INT` and this cannot be changed. If you return nothing, the return value defaults to 0. Do not use it for anything other than a status code; use result sets or output parameters for anything that's not (even if it does happen to fit an `INT`; a common mistake is to use it for identity values, which will work fine unless you ever need to upgrade to a `BIGINT`, at which point it will turn out to be a very painful decision).

Comment: @s5s . . . This is explained in the documentation:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-2017.

Comment: Adding to the comment by @JeroenMostert, the return value is automatically set to non-zero on error and zero on success to facilitate checking for success/warning/error in T-SQL. It's often ignored nowadays in T-SQL and app code in favor of structured error handling.

Comment: @Larnu: well.... `CREATE PROCEDURE foo AS BEGIN SELECT 1 / 0 END`, `SET XACT_ABORT OFF; DECLARE @r INT; EXEC @r = foo; SELECT @r` gives `-6` for me. Interestingly, that appears to be documented exactly nowhere.

Comment: @Lanu, it applies to user stored procedures too. If not explicitly set otherwise and an error is raised, the return code will be the negative value of the highest error severity minus 10. For example, proc `CREATE PROC dbo.usp_test AS SELECT 1/0; RETURN;` will result in a -6 return code.

Comment: You're right, might be misremembering something .